# Entering to program mode in ESP8286

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Trying to upload programm from Arduino IDE to ESP-WROOM-02 according [description](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=68241).

[image]

I tried to enter program mode by following procedure below:

```
Press both the RESET button and PROGRAM Button together.
Leave the RESET button alone and keep Pressing the PROGRAM button for 1 more second.
Leave the PROGRAM Button, now you are in UART Download mode.
```

But my Arduino IDE reported:

```
the selected serial port _
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

I was trying to connect terminal to serial port and I found array of bytes issued after pressing `reset`. I was trying to record these bytes by using different communication speed:

```
9600:
22 19 36 86 96 79 83 19 87 
19200:
A1 09 42 C2 EB 0A 0B C2 A3 D5 28 99 AD E1 54 FB 
38400:
62 84 A4 64 E4 84 86 85 A4 A6 85 A4 84 85 A7 86 E5 87 C4 87 E4 A6 A6 46 43 A3 C4 C4 A7 A4 A7 C4 A7 44 F3 
57600:
47 01 C4 5A 06 98 51 05 40 40 48 64 49 95 77 0B CC 51 3B 6B 43 50 40 E6 6F 0B D4 57 5A 35 B5 46 99 14 44 54 5B 63 9B 6D 0A C8 57 06 D0 57 86 0B F1
```

What might be wrong in my system? What kind of information module is trying to send me?

Comment: Why is the +5V not hooked up on the converter?

Comment: @RonBeyer - there's no appropriate place in the depicted circuit where the 5v line *could* be connected.  The circuit shows something powered at 3v3.

Comment: From the link the OP posted, somebody found that it worked by tying IO2 to +3v3 to put it in UART mode.

Comment: Two things to try: 1) add or increase the capacitor on the module's 3V3 pin. 2) Increase the baud rate to 115,200, which is the default upload speed for ESP8266.